# Sharepoint REST call to get file by ID - GetFileById fail on 404

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

There are some files. when I'm trying to get their content by ID (`GetFileById`) I'm getting `404 Not found` error.  I'm getting the file unique id from the item properties and then trying to get the content, and then it fails. Interesting that, in many cases when I'm trying to get same file by relative URL `GetFileByServerRelativeUrl` I'm getting : `The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value` error.

So, I actually don't have any option to download the file.
Any advise is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: What (and how long) is the URI in the Item properties ``__metadata`` property??

Comment: @DannyEngelmanNVP, the relative path of the file is about 218 chars, full path is 303.

Comment: If you got the list of files with a (verbose) REST call, The correct URI will be in the ``__metadata`` section

Comment: @DannyEngelmanNVP, at this stage I'm getting list of items in the list / document library using web service Lists.getListItems. So, can you please provide analog to the same __metadata in this case ? I have all the item metadata and taking all the values from there. Thanks

Comment: Start learning REST from here: http://michaelsoriano.com/understanding-sharepoint-rest-api-part-1-selecting-items/

Comment: @DannyEngelmanNVP, We are migrating to REST but it's taking time, it's a productive product and at this stage it's work with web services and file download is running on REST, so thanks or advise to learn REST, but it doesn't helps me to solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: But it will give you the correct URI to get that file with REST, and thus give you an indication where you go wrong constructing the URI

Comment: @DannyEngelmanNVP, Maybe I misexplained myself, there is a document library (customer's) with many documents, on big part of the documents are downloaded fine with my REST code, and only some documents are failing, so I assume that getfilebyid for this site and document library is working, and the problem only with some documents, probably just because their name is long or they are inside folders. So, creating an URI from the document metadata is mostly working, now I'm trying to understand why running same REST URL with unique id of another item is failing. Thanks

Comment: Publishing? Checked Out files? Only minor versions created by another user.... Get the URI SP server gives you when you call for all Items, if that URI fails you know it is not a syntax issue. If the URI SP provides you works, you know your syntax is wrong. Like Sherlock says.. Elementary my dear Watson.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear, where you trying to retrieving file from a custom list or form a library. 
If you are trying achieve with a list this link may useful [Operation with File attachment on a list](https://kushanlahiru.wordpress.com/2016/05/14/file-attach-to-sharepoint-2013-list-custom-using-angular-js-via-rest-api/)

---

Else if you are performing with library, can be done with following end point

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/Files
method: GET
```

Make file name and folder name exist before you perform the query. This should work!!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, it's talking about attachments in the list item, in my case it's a document from the document library.

Comment: @SlavaG > Same concept applies, just matter of getting idea and apply :) Do you still have this issue?